# Data type mistmatch in criteria expression MS Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

Have tried multiple attempts at figuring out.

Have a form that acts as a search form "frm_Search2017"
Within it are several unbound fields, some text boxes, some date, and some combo boxes.

On the form there is a subform that when you hit search, it runs as a search script and populates based on the data entered. It works just fine when you don't fill in any fields. It also works just fine with the date & all of the text boxes and ONE of the combo boxes.

Several search fields work just fine, but a couple of the combo boxes do not work at all and yield a Run-time error 3464 error message.

Below, the OpenedBy, ticket number, Opened Date From, Opened Date To, Due Date From, Due Date To, & Title fields work.

I'm not sure where to look next.

```
This is my search script: 
Private Sub Clear_Click()
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Search2017"
End Sub

Private Sub Search_Click()
Const cInvalidDateError As String = "You have entered an invalid date."
Dim strWhere As String
Dim strError As String

strWhere = "1=1"


' If OpenedBy
If Nz(Me.openedby) <> "" Then
    'Add it to the predicate - exact match
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.openedby = '" & Me.openedby & "'"
End If

' If Status
If Nz(Me.statusID) <> "" Then
    'Add it to the predicate - exact match
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.statusID = '" & Me.statusID & "'"
End If

 ' if ticket number
 If Nz(Me.TSCTicket) <> "" Then
'Add it to the predicate - exact match
  strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.[vendorticketID] = '" & Me.[TSCTicket] & "'"
  End If

 ' If deviceID
If Nz(Me.DeviceID) <> "" Then
    'Add it to the predicate - exact match
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.deviceID = '" & Me.DeviceID & "'"
End If

 ' If Priority
If Nz(Me.Priority) <> "" Then
    'Add it to the predicate - exact match
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.priorityID = '" & Me.Priority & "'"
End If

' If Opened Date From
If IsDate(Me.OpenedDateFrom) Then
    ' Add it to the predicate - exact
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.[dateopened] >= " & GetDateFilter(Me.OpenedDateFrom)
ElseIf Nz(Me.OpenedDateFrom) <> "" Then
    strError = cInvalidDateError
End If

' If Opened Date To
If IsDate(Me.OpenedDateTo) Then
    ' Add it to the predicate - exact
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.[dateopened] <= " & GetDateFilter(Me.OpenedDateTo)
ElseIf Nz(Me.OpenedDateTo) <> "" Then
    strError = cInvalidDateError
End If

' If Due Date From
If IsDate(Me.DueDateFrom) Then
    ' Add it to the predicate - exact
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.[dateclosed] >= " & GetDateFilter(Me.DueDateFrom)
ElseIf Nz(Me.DueDateFrom) <> "" Then
    strError = cInvalidDateError
End If

 ' If Due Date To
If IsDate(Me.DueDateTo) Then
    ' Add it to the predicate - exact
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.[dateclosed] <= " & GetDateFilter(Me.DueDateTo)
ElseIf Nz(Me.DueDateTo) <> "" Then
    strError = cInvalidDateError
End If

' If Title
If Nz(Me.Title) <> "" Then
    ' Add it to the predicate - match on leading characters
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND " & "pacs_issues.issuedescription Like '*" & Me.Title & "*'"
End If


If strError <> "" Then
    MsgBox strError
Else
    'DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_search_Browse All Issues2017", acFormDS, , strWhere, acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
    If Not Me.FormFooter.Visible Then
        Me.FormFooter.Visible = True
        DoCmd.MoveSize Height:=Me.WindowHeight + Me.FormFooter.Height
    End If
    Me.[frm_search_Browse All Issues2017].Form.Filter = strWhere
    Me.[frm_search_Browse All Issues2017].Form.FilterOn = True
End If
End Sub

Function GetDateFilter(dtDate As Date) As String
' Date filters must be in MM/DD/YYYY format
GetDateFilter = "#" & Format(dtDate, "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM") & "#"
End Function
```

Comment: A data type mismatch would indicate your field is different than the value you're validating it against.  Take statusID for example.  Is this numeric?  If so you need to ditch the quotes.  Same for deviceID.

Comment: thanks for that reminder. i've rectified it and now it's working as desired... It's been a long long long time since I've done anything with Access.